# Carbon event "consuming"

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, keyboard-shortcuts, macos-carbon

I have a problem, which is the opposite to problem described here: [cocoa-global-shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135061/cocoa-global-shortcuts). Example: when I assigning "a" key as shortcut (without modifiers) every time I press "a" my callback fired, but other applications don't get "a" press: TextEdit, XCode, etc. I don't want to "consume" the event.
Here is the code:

```
 EventTypeSpec eventTypePressed = { kEventClassKeyboard, kEventHotKeyPressed };
 InstallApplicationEventHandler(&HotKeyPressedHandler, 1, &eventTypePressed, self, NULL);

 EventTypeSpec eventTypeReleased = { kEventClassKeyboard, kEventHotKeyReleased };
 InstallApplicationEventHandler(&HotKeyReleasedHandler, 1, &eventTypeReleased, self, NULL);

  EventHotKeyID eventHotKeyID = { 'htky', 1 };
  RegisterEventHotKey(shortcut.code, shortcut.flags, eventHotKeyID, GetApplicationEventTarget(), 0, &_eventHotKeyRef);

OSStatus HotKeyPressedHandler(EventHandlerCallRef nextHandler, EventRef theEvent, void *userData) {
    ShortcutHandler* handler = userData;
    [handler.delegate keyWasPressed:handler];
    return CallNextEventHandler(nextHandler, theEvent);
}

OSStatus HotKeyReleasedHandler(EventHandlerCallRef nextHandler, EventRef theEvent, void *userData) {
    ShortcutHandler* handler = userData;
    [handler.delegate keyWasReleased:handler];
    return CallNextEventHandler(nextHandler, theEvent);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Same problem here. Do you have found a solution?